# When event loop starts?

Tags: node.js, event-loop

I’ve recently started to figure out what event loop really is and that confused me a lot, seems like I don’t know how nodejs works..
I mean when program starts, gets loaded into memory - what’s next?

I can’t see a place inside event loop where all sync. Code executes (like for/ while cycles that’s computes something).. doesn’t that means that V8 executes JavaScript and starts event loop when needed?

If anybody can help and explain how nodejs runtime is functioning on the high level would be really great

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend reading this [Asynchrony: Now & Later](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/async%20%26%20performance/ch1.md)

and I'll quote some things that I've once read.

........

JS Engine know nothing about code being asynchronous,It only execute code at a time and finishes..no more no less

the JS host environment is the one who has an implementation of the event-loop concept where code that doesn't need to run now(in the future),is waiting(imagine a network call/ io call) to finish processing and get called (be added to the event-queue of the event-loop and then executed at a next tick)

At program start,I'm 100% sure but I think all code is added to the event-queue(the way how the event-loop is implemented) and it's processed as First in First out (FIFO) which means the earlier the code the first is executed,and while running if some code need to be stalled like a setTimeout or IO process or an Ajax call(which both need time) it's up to them to use for example a callback to call(here the callback is added to the event-queue) and it's the event-loop responsibility to execute these callback in order that they've reached in at a next future tick.